# Is it possible to include a forward slash in a route dynamic property?

Tags: 8, routes

Is it possible to include forward slashes in routing parameters?

```
// routing.yml
mymodule.route
    path: '/mymodule/{param}'
    defaults:
        path: ''
    requirements
        path: '[A-Za-z0-9\-\/]+'
```

`/mymodule/this/is/a/single/param` would then result in

```
$param = 'this/is/a/single/param';
```

being passed into the controller method.

Comment: Certainly seem to be: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Answer (score 1):

I tested this out, and it doesn't work in Drupal 8, unfortunately.

```
mymodule.test:
  path: '/mymodule/{testparam}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\TestController::build'
    _title: 'Variable Parameter'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    testparam: .+
```

It picks up the route with "/mymodule/hello", but not "/mymodule/hello/world".

There's some more discussion of this here:
[Slashes in single route parameter or other ways to handle a menu tail with dynamic number of params](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175758/slashes-in-single-route-parameter-or-other-ways-to-handle-a-menu-tail-with-dynam)

It looks like there's a solution, but it's pretty heavy handed.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187497/57167 doesn't look too bad!

Comment: You could easily add a parameter with alternate separator.  /mymodule/arg1:arg2:arg3:arg4:arg5:arg6

Comment: Yeah, @Tim, I guess it doesn't.  I haven't tried it out though.  I'm surprised they don't add this.  Hopefully, in Drupal 9 they will.

Comment: Symfony supports it, they manually removed the option in drupal 8.0-beta-14