# Wildcard for routes

Tags: 8, routes

How can I pass the complete path arguments to a route defined in a mymodule.routing.yml file?

```
example_archive.content_archiv:
  path: '/examplearchiv/{myvalue}'
  defaults:
  _controller: '\Drupal\example_archiv\Controller\exampleArchiveController::content_archiv'
   _title: 'example Archive'
requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
    myvalue: .+
```

For example:

- /examplearchiv/testvalue gives $myvalue = 'testvalue' to the controller
- /examplearchiv/testvalue/value1 causes a "page not found" error
- /examplearchiv/testvalue/value1/value2 causes a "page not found" error

According to http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html `myvalue: .+` should also return slashes for {myvalue}; `$myvalue` should be `'testvalue/test1'`.

Comment: I am not sure why this wont work in your case. It should as per [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/using-parameters-in-routes). Apparently seems your route config has some problem with indentation. If so, it can cause the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Drupal 8 doesn't support this natively.  You can add a simple class in a custom module that implements the [InboundPathProcessorInterface](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175758/slashes-in-single-route-parameter-or-other-ways-to-handle-a-menu-tail-with-dynam#answer-187497) that will allow this.

Comment: Careful with inbountPathProcessors - they influence your menu and a few other things.