# get routing several directories down

Tags: 8, routes

I have a routing.yml file which has the following path:
 path: '/downloads/{path_dir}'

it works fine when the url is `/downloads/diana` for example.

but when the url is `/downloads/diana/cast` then it says "page not found"  .
How can i make this work an unlimited amount of subdirectories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slashes in single route parameter or other ways to handle a menu tail with dynamic number of params](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175758/slashes-in-single-route-parameter-or-other-ways-to-handle-a-menu-tail-with-dynam#answer-187497)

Comment: Hi I have tried the answer on that page (the second one which requires a new class, since the first one says it will not work.  ) That one doesnt work either , the second one.  There must be an easier way I would think this is something that is very needed.

Comment: The second answer involves the query string! The first answer will work like desired by you, using the uri.

Comment: According to the post it says it doesn't work

Comment: Hi Remy the first answer does not work for me