# EventSubscriber returning correct content but status code is 404

Tags: 8, routes, redirection, event-subscribers

As the title says, content is being returned correctly but the status code is `404`.

I have checked the .htaccess file and the Apache config file as well. All seems to be fine.

I have the following in my module routing file:

```
my_module.news_list:
  path: /api/{state}/news
  defaults:
    _controller: Drupal\my_module\Controller\NewsController::index
  methods: [GET]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

This is the function that does the redirect in my EventSubscriber

```
public function redirectRequestToModule(GetResponseEvent $event) {
            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $validPathBegins = ['/men', '/nat'];
            // This is necessary because this also gets called on
            // node sub-tabs such as "edit", "revisions", etc.  This
            // prevents those pages from being redirected.
            $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();
            if (!in_array(substr($requestUri, 0, 4), $validPathBegins)) {
                return;
            }
            
            $node = $request->attributes->get('node');
            
            // get the configured request query parameters for this content type
            
            $redirect_url = '/api' . $requestUri;
            $kernel = $event->getKernel();
            $response = $kernel->handle(Request::create($redirect_url));
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
```

This is what I type in the browser: `mysite.com/nat/news/`

The content returned is correct but the status code is `404`.

P.S There isn't a reachable path on my Drupal website like `/nat/news`. The path mentioned is supposed to return a list of news articles.

Comment: This is a bit confusing what you want to achieve. There are different concepts, redirecting, subrequesting and aliasing. The latter is what I would prefer in this case, which is not only possible through the core alias table, but also through a custom path processor converting the external path `/nat/news` to an internal path matching a route.

Comment: Thanks. Creating an alias in `/admin/config/search/path/add` worked. I created an alias `/api/nat/news/` to `/nat/news`

Comment: If you have a large number of aliases all with the same pattern you can do this programmatically, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187497/47547

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes it much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an alias in `/admin/config/search/path/add` worked. I created an alias `/api/nat/news/` to `/nat/news`

Thanks [4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4) for a much easier solution [drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187497/47547](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187497/47547)